# Visual Studio 2013 search and replace regular expression copy to clipboard

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible in Visual Studio when you use Search and Replace with Regular Expression option to copy all results to clipboard?

It's a text file, so I guess I could create a quick console app that will iterate the lines and grab them that way. But just wondering if there was a quicker way?

For example,

```
ListOne
ListTwo
```

My RegEx is grabbing everything to right of word List and I want to copy that to clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

When you used the advanced find / replace (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>) that will output the replaced strings to the Find Results 1 or 2 windows. You can copy and paste it from there.